# How to collect trace in oracle 11g and 12c?

Tags: oracle11g, oracle12c

Hi i am using Oracle `11g` and `12c`. We are trying to achieve scenario navigation and want to collect background oracle queries. Let's say i am doing activity like login to the application and now i wanted to know what queries are getting used during login activity. Like this we have multiple scenario and have to capture the queries behind it. Can somebody please help me to get this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are various ways to generate trace files but since you want to capture everything you can turn it on at the database level:-

```
ALTER SYSTEM SET sql_trace = true SCOPE=MEMORY;
```

once you've completed your testing turn it off (really as soon as you can)

```
ALTER SYSTEM SET sql_trace = false SCOPE=MEMORY;
```

The output will be placed in the diagnostic directory. Something like

```
$ORACLE_BASE/diag/rdbms/sid/SID/trace
```

You can make the output a little easier to read by running it through tkprof

```
tkprof trace.trc trace.txt
```

There are other options for tracing a session that you might prefer (these are mostly reviewed [here](https://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/sql-trace-10046-trcsess-and-tkprof)).

This will work for both 11g and 12c.

Comment: how to filter if there are to many background threads are executing ? how we will fetch only those statement are executed using user login ?

Comment: If you want to trace one particular session then you can use one of the methods in the link, otherwise you get everyone.  You can sort the tkprof output with sort=userid to group the queriss to each user together which might help.

Comment: When we login through application we would not sure abt the what session id is getting used also the userid you are talking about is the database user or application ? The problem is that user is also getting used by some other process so in this case its very tough to figure it out which query is properly getting used during login process.